# H2 error [90011-187]

Tags: database, h2

I am trying to create a database in linux where:

1. Its not in the user home
2. Don't require the client to inform the entire server path for the db file.
3. Needs to be different from the bin directory to prevent core dump failures.

The documentation says that you can use a url like this:

```
jdbc:h2:file:data/sample
```

but this simple url doesn't work and get the follow error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path
that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not
allowed in the database URL
"jdbc:h2:file:db/datadb;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3". Use an absolute path,
~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-187]
```

Observation: I know you can use ".", but what will be the url from the client in that case?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is wrong. I will update it.

```
jdbc:h2:file:data/sample
```

It should be:

```
jdbc:h2:file:./data/sample
```

Many users ran into problems because they used something like `jdbc:h2:test` and then either didn't find the database file, or created a second database when running the application in a different directory. That's why in version 1.4.x, now relative path only work when using `.`, as in `jdb:h2:./test`.

By the way, you have asked this question [in the H2 Google Group as well](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/unXTI-ip3Q8).